# How does the implementation of page parameter affects the bounce rate of the page

Tags: google-analytics, bounce

I have applied page parameters on my landing page due to multiple items. Once the user scroll down to bottom there comes an option for going to page 2 , page 3 and so on. After clicking on the next page number url changes. Does that change in url is included in my original landing page or is counted as separate page. And does this change in URL affects my bounce rate

Answer (score 0):

The parameters themselves have no influence on the bounce rate. The bounce rate is affected based on the number of interactions sent to Analytics. If a session sends only the first pageview it will have 100% bounce, if another interaction is sent when clicking on the page number then that session will not be a bounce.